# How to add google map in an iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, iframe

I want to show a map direction to the user and I want to show this map in a popup iframe tag.  How we can show this map in iframe tag

[Here is the link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/31.5282618,74.3234164/University+of+South+Asia,+47+Tufail+Rd,+Lahore/@31.5308165,74.3164608,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m10!4m9!1m1!4e1!1m5!1m1!1s0x3919050d90b4fac3:0xa46dbb2def95e45a!2m2!1d74.3781741!2d31.5328815!3e) which I want to show in iframe tag in my code

I do not know why this is not working.  Thanks in advance for your great thoughts

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
<style>
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
height:auto;
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
    
@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)} 
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">View Map Direction</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
  
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      
    </div>

    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/31.5282618,74.3234164/University+of+South+Asia,+47+Tufail+Rd,+Lahore/@31.5308165,74.3164608,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m10!4m9!1m1!4e1!1m5!1m1!1s0x3919050d90b4fac3:0xa46dbb2def95e45a!2m2!1d74.3781741!2d31.5328815!3e"></iframe>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
   
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are trying to load map in iframe and iframs's 'X-Frame-Option' is set to 'SAMEORIGIN'. so it is not load in iframe.
You can't set X-Frame-Options on the iframe. That is a response header set by the domain from which you are requesting the resource (www.google.com in your example). They have set the header to SAMEORIGIN in this case, which means that they have disallowed loading of the resource in an iframe outside of their domain. For more information see The [X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) on MDN.

You can add map in iframe using below link:
[How to load a Google Map in an iframe with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190813/how-to-load-a-google-map-in-an-iframe-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the embedded link of a place from the google map in the src.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3945.5366640845264!2d76.93905241410239!3d8.544280398746274!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3b05b96a8025dc21%3A0x433a8ad4eeb21137!2sB-Hub!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1551781850948" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```